# Unable to display information after using React Routes with "Lifting state up"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm learning React Router from textbook and facing a problem when changing from `Switch` to `Routes` with the new function of Lifting State Up. I can't display text after clicking the 'News' link. Here shows the code:

`/* index.jsx */`

```
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
    const root = createRoot(rootElement);

    root.render(
    <HashRouter>

    <Routes>
      <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
      <Route path='/news' element={<News />} />
    </Routes>
    </HashRouter>,
    );
```

`/* About.jsx */` <- good code

```
const About = () => (
<div>
  <Menu />
  <h1>這裡是關於我們 This is about us.</h1>
</div>
);

export default About;
```

[image]

`/* News.jsx */` <- Problem comes in.

```
const News = () => {
  const [news] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: 'News1', describe: 'A wins！' },
    { id: 2, name: 'News2', describe: 'B wins！' },
  ]);


  return (
    <div>

      <Menu />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/news/*' element={<><p>hello!</p><NewsList 
news={news} /></>} />
        <Route path='newsReader/:id' element={<><NewsReader news ={news} /></>} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
};

export default News;
```

[image]

It should be like this:

[image]

I believe the problem lies in `<Route path>` but can't find the solution.

The code `<NewsList>` and `<NewsReader>` is here:

```
const NewsList = props =>  (
        <ul>
            {
                props.news.map(theNews => (
                    <li key = {theNews.id}>
                        <Link to = {`/news/newsReader/${theNews.id}`}> 
   {theNews.name}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    );


    export default NewsList;


    const NewsReader = (props) => {
       const {id:targetNewsId} = useParams();
       const targetNews = props.news.find(theNews => (
        String(theNews.id) === String(targetNewsId)
       ));

        return(
            <div>
                <h1>你正在閱讀 You are now reading {targetNews.name}</h1>
                <p>{targetNews.describe}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

export default NewsReader;
```

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani it should be v6. My VS code complains when I use the <switch> function.

Comment: `const [news]` looks suspicious to me. Maybe you wanted to use `const news`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested routes, you need to follow the below approach

// index.js -> /news/*

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
<HashRouter>

<Routes>
  <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
  <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
  <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
  <Route path='/news/*' element={<News />} /> // here you need to /*
</Routes>
</HashRouter>,
);
```

For the News.jsx you need to have relative path to /news like below

```
const News = () => {
  const [news] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: 'News1', describe: 'A wins！' },
    { id: 2, name: 'News2', describe: 'B wins！' },
  ]);


  return (
    <div>

      <Menu />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/*' element={<><p>hello!</p><NewsList 
news={news} /></>} />
        <Route path='newsReader/:id' element={<><NewsReader news ={news} /></>} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
};

export default News;
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! May I know what the use of lifting the state up is?